# Is it wise to use generics for exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

My team is in the middle of cleaning up our use of `throws Exception` and either removing or replacing them with specific exceptions.

A common throws is because an entity was not found. Should we be throwing a generic `NotFoundException` or a specific `SomeClassNotFoundException` for each entity class?

If we should be throwing a specific exception, should we be creating a specific Exception class for each entity type? Can we safely use generics? Like this `class NotFoundException<T extends EntityBaseClass> extends Exception` and then the constructor takes care of declaring what Entity type we're dealing with?

If we should be throwing a specific exception and not using generics, should those exceptions extend or implement a `NotFoundException` abstract class or interface?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple litmus test for the question

> Should we be creating a specific Exception class for each entity type?

is

> Are there any circumstances where we would need to write a `catch` clause that will catch a "not found" exception thrown by some class X **and not by any other class**?

If the answer is "yes", then a separate `ClassXNotFoundException` is warranted; otherwise, it probably isn't.

As to the second half of your question, the language doesn't permit the use of generics for exception types.

Answer (score 29):

It's not allowed to make exceptions generic - it won't compile ([JLS §8.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)):

> It is a compile-time error if a generic class is a direct or indirect subclass of Throwable

Since type parameters of generics are erased at runtime, there is no way to distinguish between generic exceptions with different type parameters in the `catch` clause, thus generic exceptions are not supported. So, you actually have no choice regarding using generic exceptions.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using:

```
public Class EntityNotFoundException<T extends EntityBaseClass> extends Exception {

}
```

You should use:

```
public Class EntityNotFoundException extends Exception {
    private Class<? extends EntityBaseClass> clazz;

    public EntityNotFoundException(Class<? extends EntityBaseClass> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    . . .
}
```

This way you can keep a reference to the Entity type that is generating the exception. To throw one of this exceptions you can use:

```
throw new EntityNotFoundException(Customer.class);
```

The compiler **will** validate that Customer does extend EntityBaseClass.

Comment: Point to be noted here that EntityNotFoundException is a duplicate name for javax.persistance.EntityNotFoundException.

Answer (score 5):

> should we be creating a specific `Exception` class for each entity type?

If the callers of your code can reasonably recover from a failure to locate an entity definition and would benefit from being able to take a different recovery strategy per entity type, then yes.  Otherwise no.

> Can we safely use generics? Like this class NotFoundException extends Exception and then the constructor takes care of declaring what Entity type we're dealing with?

It won't help callers of your code switch on the entity type related to the failure.

Even if you define an exception type `MyParameterizedException<T>` then due to type-erasure, the caller cannot do

```
 try {
   callYourCode();
 } catch (MyParameterizedException<TypeA> ex) {
   // some handling code
 } catch (MyParameterizedException<TypeB> ex) { 
   // some different handling code for type b
 }
```

because with type erasure it looks like

```
 try {
   callYourCode();
 } catch (MyParameterizedException ex) {
   // some handling code
 } catch (MyParameterizedException ex) { 
   // some different handling code for type b
 }
```

and the second `catch` block would be unreachable code and so will be rejected at compile time by `javac`.  The first catch block would be entered for type b and type a entities (and any other types as well).

> If we should be throwing a specific exception and not using generics, should those exceptions extend or implement a `NotFoundException` abstract class or interface?

If the callers of your code would be surprised if they did not then yes.

If the callers of your code would benefit from having entity failures handled by code that handles other `NotFoundException`s then yes.

If the callers of your code would likely not want to have failures to locate an entity type definition handled in the same way as other `NotFound` conditions then no.

Answer (score 0):

I think everybody answer is saying you don't need a specific exception. I was looking at how Hibernate defines not found exception. I found [EntityNotFoundException](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException.html) I would add that you should NOT even create your own exception, just reuse this one. It extends RuntimeException which means you are not forcing people to catch it. But if you want to then you can reuse an existing class in J2EE. Which is always better than writing new code.